# By clicking one checkbox other checkbox should be disable

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I've 2 columns with checkboxes when one column is checked all respective are checked likewise in 2nd column but the problem is here, client wants when One column of checkbox is checked then 2nd column will be disable or throw alert message to check only one column at a time?

```
function SelectAll1(headerchk, gridId) {

        var gvcheck = document.getElementById(gridId);
        var i, j;
        if (headerchk.checked) {
            for (i = 0; i < gvcheck.rows.length - 1; i++) {
                var inputs = gvcheck.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
               for (j = 1; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                 if (inputs[j].type == "checkbox") {
                        inputs[j].checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; i < gvcheck.rows.length - 1; i++) {
                var inputs = gvcheck.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
                 for (j = 1; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                   if (inputs[j].type == "checkbox") {
                        inputs[j].checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can ch

Comment: post your HTML also

Comment: How is this related to C#?

Comment: Change inputs[j].checked = true; to inputs[j].checked = headerchk.checked; Then you can eliminate the if

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you're trying to do without the HTML but here's a start you can build off.

```js
var selected = $('.check:checked').length;

if (selected >= 1) {
  $('.check').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
```

Answer (score 0):

From the little info given I assume this:

`SelectAll1` clear or set all checkboxes in column 1.
`SelectAll2` clear or set all checkboxes in column 2.
`headerchk` is a checkbox when clicked clears or sets all.

Do this change:

1. After each line in the code where `SelectAll1(`*headerchk*, *gridId*`)` is called you change it to `SelectAll1(`*headerchk*`.checked`, *gridId*`)`.
2. Insert another line below this line with a negation:
   `SelectAll2(!`*headerchk*.`checked`, *gridId*`)`
3. After each line in the code where `SelectAll2(`*headerchk*, *gridId*`)` is called you change it to `SelectAll2(`*headerchk*`.checked`, *gridId*`)`.
4. Insert another line below this line with a negation:
   `SelectAll1(!`*headerchk*`.checked`, *gridId*`)`

You only showed me the code for `SelectAll1`, so I assume `SelectAll2` is the same when you not yet know how to make them different. Correct me if this is not the fact!

5. Continue by change the function `SelectAll1` to the following:

---

```
function SelectAll1(header_checked, gridId) {
    var gvcheck = document.getElementById(gridId);
    var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < gvcheck.rows.length - 1; i++) {
        var inputs = gvcheck.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (j = 1; j < inputs.length; j++) {
            if (inputs[j].type == "checkbox") {
                inputs[j].checked = header_checked;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The else-part and if is eliminated by moving the condition to the assignment that is eiher true or false. The `.checked` part is moved outside the function.

---

6. Do the same change in `SelectAll2`
7. Test if it works and report to me!